# Get event name already being observed

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I need to check event name already attached/ observed on an element.

```
//foo is a button
var isEventObserved = ?// need help in this line
var evnName = ?;// how
If(isEventObserved && evnName === 'my:evn2')
{
     $('foo').observe('my:evn1', mymethod1};
}
else
{
   $('foo').observe('my:env2', mymethod2);
}
```

Comment: How come you don't know whether it already is attached? How don't you even know the event name (`click`)?

Comment: events are attached dynamically. Also I changed the code to show my real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for

`Event.cache[$('foo')._prototypeUID]` lists the events registered for the element.

`Event.cache[$('foo')._prototypeUID]['element']` is a reference to the element being observed, the rest of the properties in the object are events registered on the element (custom or native)

so for your specific situation

```
if(Event.cache[$('foo')._prototypeUID]['my:evn2'] != undefined)
{
    $('foo').observe('my:evn1', mymethod1);
}
else
{
    $('foo').observe('my:env2', mymethod2);
}
```

Please note I tested this with the latest version of Prototype, 1.7.2

Comment: It does work in PrototypeJS 1.7.1, see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xdN5X/ but if you copied and pasted from above - I noticed a typo I made and fixed.